# In Rails 3 and HAML 3.0.25, any variable displayed inside of :plain could be a security issue, because it is automatically html_safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

It seems like if I have any variable and display it as a string, it needs to call a method to return the `html_safe` version (a new object of different class), to avoid any XSS attacks.

But if in

```
:plain
  some content
  some more content...
  the value is #{foo}
```

then they are automatically `html_safe`.   Wouldn't this be a security loophole, when someone isn't aware of it?  Is it true that either Rails or HAML might have something to prevent it?  For example, HAML can have something like, string literals is automatically `html_safe`, but if there is any variable added or interpolated, then don't automatically mark it html_safe?

Answer (score 0):

I think the purpose for `:plain` is to use with large block non-html text.

Please ref `:plain` section on http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html

So who use `:plain` should make sure that the user input's HTML tags have been filtered by using something like `sanitize`.

Comment: reference that page for what?  Does that page mention this security issue?  You answer is the "I think"... and "Programmers **should** make sure".  Yeah, if everybody "should" everything, then no security issue will occur.  What I am saying is why it is not handled the other way, and you are saying "programmers should be careful." yeah, we all know that.

Comment: If you take a look on the Filters > :plain part in the reference, you will see `This is useful for large blocks of text without HTML tags, when you don’t want lines starting with . or - to be parsed.`. If you want to escape HTML by default, you don't use `:plain`, but `:escape` which is explained as `Works the same as plain, but HTML-escapes the text before placing it in the document`. I agree the first `I think` is somewhat misleading as it is actually a truth. And it is my fault that didn't mention what should be mentioned.

Comment: Programer `should` make sure not because of he really should. It's because he is using `:plain` which is well-documented as non-escaping and so the programmer should take his own risk. So I would use `:plain` with well-treated user inputs and mostly text from trusted people (such as teammate who write static pages).

Comment: The `:plain` can be for large block of text, but it doesn't have to.  What I am saying is, shouldn't `haml` or Rails 3 together make it so that it is not `html_safe`.  This is true with other Rails 3 output, and if just leaving a potential loophole here, it is not that good.  It is not about "programmers should be careful"